# Collapsing archives issue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, archive

I'm using a plugin collapsing archives.I want the plugin to display only category "news". I've set the plugin to only include this category. But the inclusion or exclusion works only at the post level.If you leave the year and/or month links active, clicking on a year or month produces an archive list of all posts.

Help please. Here's the code http://pastebin.com/FM2pLQQQ

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. I just added

```
    function only_show_blog_posts( $query ) {
   // Only modify the main loop query
   // on the front end
   if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
      // Only modify date-based archives
      if ( is_date() ) {
         // Only display posts from category ID 1
         $query->set( 'cat', '4' );
      }
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_show_blog_posts' );
```

to the end of the collapsingArchList.php worked like a charm!